# jcombobox actionperformed event

Tags: java, swing, events, netbeans, jcombobox

i am finding it difficult figuring our how the jcombobox actionperformed event works. I have a form which contains a jcombobox and jtable. Change in jcombobox results in data being updated in the jtable. To implement this, I implemented the actionperformed event for the jcombobox. This code contains certain checks and validations and warnings for users before updating the values in the jtable. The problem I am facing is that when the form loads for the 1st time, the actionperformed event for the jcombobox is getting called. This is causing unnecessary validations and resulting in behaviour which is not required. Can somebody please throw some light on this behaviour of the jcombobox actionperformed event.

Comment: The action is not triggered by just loading the form. Can you please provide a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) which shows us your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have look at [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for handling events from JComboBox, even some description in [JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) implements [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Thanks mKorbel...that worked for me. :-) I was also making a mistake while loading the items and setting the default item in the jcomboboxmodel...so now i first fill the model, then i set the default selection and then assign the model to the jcombobox. :-)