# Display JList elements from model

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model, jlist

I have a list of Objects `Person (int age, String name)` that are stored in a `DefaultListModel` to be assigned to the `JList`.

```
DefaultListModel model;
model = new DefaultListModel();

Person p = new Person(43,"Tom");
//insert in the model
model.add(size, p);

jList1.setModel(model);
```

I would like to display only the name in the `JList`, but I cannot figure out how to do it without using another list of Names (which I would prefer to avoid).

Is there any easy way to tell the `JList` which attribute of the object `Person` to display?

Comment: Read the discussions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173325/execute-an-action-when-an-item-on-the-combobox-is-selected-netbeans/15173525

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of the view should be the domain of the `ListCellRenderer`

Something like...

```
public class PersonCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof Person) {
            setText(((Person)value).getName());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

To apply the render to the list, you need to do...

```
jList1.setCellRenderer(new PersonCellRenderer());
```

Take a look at [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information

Comment: and don't forget to write a custom KeySelectionManager because just using a renderer will break the default functionality of the combo box.

Comment: @camickr Hahaha, knew that was comming ;) - But `JList` doesn't support `KeySelectionManager`

Comment: Wasn't paying attention :) Your right, its worse for a JList. Instead you have to override the `getNextMatch(...)` method of JList, which is worse then just plugging in a KeySelectionManager. This is another reason I don't like this approach. Users don't care about the code, they just want to see the standard functionality. And don't forget to implement Comparable on the Person class so you can sort the people in proper order when displayed in the list. So much extra work to do...

Comment: @camickr Sorting would be the models responsibility, but it's still a fair point.  Generally, I just attach a search mechanism to allow me to filter the list, but that's just me. Besides, I've been using Swing for 13 years and didn't know you could do "first character" matching for either of these components ;)

Comment: Thats my point. If the only the renderer knows what to display then how can you expect the model to do the sorting? Seems like we are getting awfully complicated here. Again sorting is a more general comment for a combo box where I would think most users expect to see the combo box in sorted order. First character matching is a common UI that any advanced user will know about. It is faster to use the keyboard to select items then it is to use the mouse.

Comment: The problem is, it is the renderers responsibility to "render" the data, that's it's job, just as it's the model's responsibility to "model" the data.  I would argue that the user "expects" the content to be sorted all the time and that the sort should alphabetical (I certainly like it some times), they might want it sorted based on some key that's not displayed, the argument is to generic.  Not everything is going to fit into the same hole.  For example, this combo box might be need to display just the first name, but some might need the "last, first" name and some other might like nick name

Comment: That's a lot of decision making to make.  Renders allow us to make these decisions without implementing the logic directly within the implementation of the object.  As you state, it's also possible to supply additional hints back to the controls (the KeySelectionManager for the combobox), so we have mechanisms to accomplish these (sure, the `JList` is a little more involved, but I use a similar solution to what NetBean's uses anyway, when they start typing, I provide a search field, which they can provide wild card searches that filter the list).  Sure out of the box, that's a lot of work.....

Comment: I agree its the renderers job to render the data. I agree its the models job to store the data. I also agree in this case a custom renderer should be created, but the answer is not complete unless the `getNextMatch(...)` is also changed since this would break the default functionality of the JList. My other comments where more directed at the last posting where I still see no problem using a reusable Item class with a well defined toString() implementation in the situation where value/description pairs are being used. Those comments should not have been made here, sorry :(

Comment: @camickr I'm happy for the decision. It highlights areas of the API that I need do more thinking about. The use of a generic `Item` class was a "demonstration" of away to link the display text with the value.  I prefer to use renderers where I can and your argument is valid.  It would need to be a weighted decision based on needs that we didn't have knowledge of. (no apologies needed for making me think ;))

Comment: @camickr in Swing, sorting/filtering is the responsibility of the _view_ - it's a short-coming of core Swing to not support it for lists just as it does for tables. SwingX remedies that, including a fixed getNextMatch() :) And again: smearing view concerns into the model is ... dirty, it simply doesn't belong there and has far-reaching effects on the whole of your class stack, as f.i. each and every collaborator of the model needs to be aware that it contains the wrapper (which may or may not be an option in a fully controlled environment, but not in the general case)

Comment: That works great.. but I think you meant :
jList1.set**Cell**Renderer(new PersonCellRenderer());

Answer (score 1):

Simply override the toString() method of your Person class to return the name of the Person

```
DefaultListModel model;
model = new DefaultListModel();

Person p = new Person(43,"Tom");
//insert in the model
model.add(size, p);

jList1.setModel(model);

public class Person {

  private int age;
  private String name;

  public Person(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
  }
}
```