# How to know what you selected in the JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I am making a Basic calculator app in java which has 2 JTextFields and 1 JComboBox. What i want to know if there is a way to let a JButton detect what you selected in the JComboBox, when i did it with the text field it looked something like this

```
 static String divide = "/";

if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                if (symbol.getText().equals(divide)){
                 <code>
              }
         }
```

So is there a similar way to do this with JComboBoxs??

```
String[] symbols = {times, minus, plus, divide};
```

That's the JComboBox's content code.

Comment: Look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173325/execute-an-action-when-an-item-on-the-combobox-is-selected
It will help you with understanding of it.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get selected item from JComboBox with method [.getSelectedItem()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()).

Say you have String[] symbols = {times, minus, plus, divide}; as an input when constructing JComboBox (see constructor [JComboBox(E[] items)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) )

```
JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(symbols);

//you will see the string you selected
System.out.println(jcb.getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use action listener

```
String[] quantities1 = {"/","+"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(quantities1);
        comboBox.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        //do stuff when a section is performed
                        //you can use comboBox.getSelectedItem() to get the selected value
                    }
                }            
        );
```